# pow$(X,Y)$ $>$ pow$(Y,X)$, if $X<Y$.

Tags: inequality, math-software, exponentiation

How can we proof following?

if $X < Y$, then:

> $X^{Y} > Y^{X}$        ,

Where X, and Y are integers. Also $X,Y > 1$.

---

Except a special case $2^{3} < 3^{2}$.

I think for other variables $X,Y$ above equation is correct.

<sub>I need to for pumping a lemma question</sub>

Comment: `Is it well known and we can leave at this stage in answer`

Comment: The title and question have the x < y condition backward, did you mean it to be like that?

Comment: @Amzoti : Yes I made mistake now corrected.

Comment: Take X = 2.0001 and Y=2.9999. do you require X and Y to be integers? Even then, take X=1, Y = N (any other integer)

Comment: Take logarithms of the two sides and use Lagrange's mean value theorem.

Comment: @CalvinLin I am working for x,y whole numbers, integers

Comment: @AmihaiZivan Xlog(Y) < Ylog(X) ok understood. thanks

Comment: @AmihaiZivan but log(Y) > log(X)..

Comment: So? Intuitively think of it as the difference in logs is not as big as the difference in x,y values.

Comment: @AmihaiZivan Ok, Is it acceptable argument na. I can finish my proof with this statement?

Comment: this is a problem iit aspirants always have at their fingertips.

Comment: @K.Ghosh Thats Good!

Comment: Also $2 < 4$ but $2^4 = 4^2$.

Comment: @DanielPietrobon Yes there are some special cases, that's why I need proof, otherwise I could stop here in pumping lemma :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x<y$, so $x^y>y^x$.

Since $\ln \alpha$ is monotonic at $(0,\infty)$ it is enough to show that $\ln x^y > \ln y^x$ which translates to $y\ln x> x\ln y \iff \frac{\ln x}{x}>\frac{\ln y}{y}$. Define  $f(\alpha)=\frac {\ln \alpha}{\alpha}$, we need to prove that $f(x)>f(y)  $ for $ x<y $.

Investagiting $f$ would yield that it has a global maximum at $\alpha=e$ and it's monotone decreasing afterwards, concluding that for $y>x>e$,  $f(y)<f(x)$, as needed.

*My comment about using mean value theorem was a mistake, sorry about that.*

Answer (score 4):

Study the behavior of $~\large \log(x^{1/x})~$ = $~\large \frac{\log(x)}{x}$.

Use the derivative = $0$ at $e$, and derivative $<0~$ for $~x>e$, so $\large x^{1/x}$ is decreasing.

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: @Amzoti You messed up the math in that edit there...

Comment: @TMM, thanks for catching and correcting!